# Visual studio packager

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

A while ago I found a packaging tool for visual studio that allowed quite heavy control by means of a build script and was a freebie , problem is I can't remember the name of it. Anyone know of a package/tool that fits those criteria? Failing that I just wanted it as I know I could do completely silent install packages with it. Which is exactly what I want for a central deploy. Oh this is in VB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything which produces an MSI file, such as WiX, can be installed silently using the /qn flag and thus matches your criteria.

Another major installer script is NSIS (Nullsoft Install System) - you can write a silent installer using this as well.

Can you remember any of the syntax or anything? WiX is XML-based, and NSIS is it's own stack-based language, although there is a plugin to make it imperative.

Comment: It was a GUI that wrote a script file. The script file was plain text and could be edited afterwards if required. WiX looks promising though.